# How to assign an array to a row of 2d array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

In scala, I am trying to assign a 1D array to one row of a 2D array

```
var data: Array[Array[AnyRef]] = _
val line = "Year,Month,Day,City"
val temp = line.split(",").toArray.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]
```

When I tried

```
data(0)=temp
```

application will suspended without further warning or error msg. What is wrong with this approach? And how to do it properly? Thank you

Comment: `data(0) = Array.ofDim[AnyRef](temp)` Take a look at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch11s12.html

Comment: I am sorry, but this method doesn't compile. I tried data(0) = Array.ofDim[AnyRef](temp) as well, but it just suspended as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data array is not initialized. Try this.

```
object TwoDArray {

  var data: Array[Array[AnyRef]] = Array.ofDim[AnyRef](100,100)
  val line = "Year,Month,Day,City"
  val temp = line.split(",").toArray.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    data(0) = temp
    data.foreach(row => {
      val arrToStr = row.mkString(" ")
      if (!arrToStr.contains("null")) println(arrToStr)
    })
  }
}
```

Update: I initialized the array as 100x100, you can make it smaller as necessary. Also, the main method is only for testing. If you don't know the size of your 2D array, you may consider other data strictures that can grow dynamically, e.g. List of Lists

Comment: Nice point, once OP initialize the array, just calling `data(0)=temp` should work.